# Eclipse/STS4: How move a View among other views but with the keyboard?

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite, sts

For Eclipse/STS4 IDE assume exists a window where in some section exists the following views together and sorted as:

```
Console
Javadoc
Progress
Search
Terminal
```

Now, if is need to move or **change the position** of the `Search` view as the second (after of the `Console` view), how to accomplish this goal with the keyboard and not with the mouse? therefore without drag and drop.

**Reason**

Accident about a cut-off in a hand's palm, so is not easy use the palm of the hand to use the mouse

Comment: I am not aware of a keyboard shortcut for this, but maybe the keyboard shortcut to jump to a specific view helps here? On my Mac, it is Cmd-F7, it shows the list of open views and let you jump to a specific one.

Comment: Huge thanks Marting, it helps a lot too - For Windows and Linux environment it its `ctrl` + `F7`